# How to concatenate 2 textboxes in wicket?

Tags: wicket

So i got these 2 text boxes and I'm trying to concatenate them together and show the result in label. I found an example and did it like in the example but something is wrong. So maybe some one can see what I am doing wrong, because i have just started and don't understand how to do it properly.

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

    private String fNumber="Big";
    private String sNumber=" text!";
    private String sResult=fNumber+sNumber;

    public HomePage() {

        PropertyModel<String> firstNumber = new PropertyModel<String>(this, "fNumber");
        PropertyModel<String> secondNumber = new PropertyModel<String>(this, "sNumber");

        add(new Label("message", "HelloWorld!"));

        add(new Label("result", sResult));

        Form<?> form = new Form("form");
        form.add(new TextField<String>("firstNumber", firstNumber));
        form.add(new TextField<String>("secondNumber", secondNumber));
        add(form);
    }
}
```

soo i have made this

`   add(new Label("message", "HelloWorld!"));

```
    add(new Label("result", new Model(numb.getsResult())));


    Form<?> form = new Form("form") ;

    form.add(new TextField<String>("firstNumber", new Model(numb.setfNumber())));
    form.add(new TextField<String>("secondNumber",new Model(numb.setsNumber())));
    add(form);`
```

and i have a class that has 3 string fields and getters and setters and sii that much i have understood last comment explained some things maybe some one know how to fix this.

Comment: I think it's best if you read this: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/working-with-wicket-models.html#WorkingwithWicketmodels-DynamicModels Basically the two things that went wrong are  that your label hasn't got a dynamic model and that you concatenate the values statically at creation time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to "recalculate" your result. The Wicket way would be to define a Model for your Label that does the concatenation.

```
add(new Label("result", new IModel<String>(){

@Override
public void detach() {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public String getObject() {
    return fNumber + sNumber;
}

@Override
public void setObject(String object) {
    // do nothing
}
}));
```

Additionally you **must** use the PropertyModels from the example.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, but it might be worth mentioning that it would be good practice to rely on models instead, and do proper detaching. Couldn't using class variables for this kind of things get you in trouble if they're something heavier than a couple of Strings?

Comment: @XaviLópez thanks. Well I thought my answer would advocate Models, ok, not the detaching kind but that wouldn't be usefull in this case. Models using Models are good but IMO beyond the scope of an SO-answer about something else, as are problems that might arise when he tries to use his Textfields for non-strings

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate two strings I usually use StringBuilder:

```
        PropertyModel firstNumber = new PropertyModel(this,"fNumber");
        PropertyModel secondNumber = new PropertyModel(this,"sNumber");
        PropertyModel resultNumber = new PropertyModel(this,"sResult");
        StringBuilder sResult = new StringBuilder((String) firstNumber.getObject());
        sResult.append((String) secondNumber.getObject());
        resultNumber.setObject(sResult.toString());
```

Also, please read the link from biziclop as it should help you significantly.